# Representing Electric circuits in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can you represent electric circuits like the one I have linked in Matlab? If the nodes were connected by transfer functions instead of capacitors, inductors and resistors this could be done by a matrix. Is there some similar method to represent electric circuits to find the relationships between the currents and voltages?

Circuit diagram:

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: Probably would have a system of equations described as a set of KCL (Kirchhoff’s Current Law) or KVL (Kirchhoff’s Voltage Law) equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, I do this sort of thing all the time. There's no way getting around the fact that you'll have to do some math, though.

Use `tf()` to define your complex impedances (ie. 1/sC, sL, and R). Maybe write some short functions:

- `circuit_series(Z1,Z2) = Z1+Z2`
- `circuit_parallel(Z1,Z2) = Z1*Z2/(Z1+Z2)`
- `voltage_divider(Z1,Z2) = Z2/(Z1+Z2)`.

Use MATLAB to sum up the total complex impedance seen by *vi*. You'll have to solve for the voltages at the intermediate nodes with the voltage divider equation before you can get to *vo*. Once you have the transfer function *vo/vi*, you can do fun things such as given an arbitrary *vi* waveform over time, compute the resulting *vo* waveform (assuming some initial conditions!).

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, electric circuits can be represented using various methods. One common approach is to use systems of linear equations, where the variables represent currents and voltages. This can be done by formulating the circuit equations using Kirchhoff's laws and then solving the resulting system of equations using matrix methods, such as Gaussian elimination or matrix inversion. As you can see on [how long to smoke ribs at 225 without foil](https://favegrills.com/how-long-to-smoke-ribs-at-225/) By representing the circuit in this way, you can determine the relationships between the currents and voltages in the circuit.